# Cannot see Keys and URI in DocumentDB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am using Azure DocumentDB.
It's been a while since the last time I used it (a couple months maybe), and now I tried going back to it.
However, it seems that something changed and now I can't see my keys and URI anymore.

This is what I see when I click on the "Keys" button:
[The red circle is where the keys and URI should be, but as you can see it's empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DP4z4.png)

I tried hitting the "Regenerate keys" button, but I get an error message in red reading:
"Regenerating Regenerating primary key succeeded key failed"

Which seems to be an error in itself.

What should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: Ethan, can you check what is the status of your Azure subscription? It seems like your account is suspended. You can check the status by clicking the key icon on the left.

Comment: Yes I've learned it later that day. Shame the error message is so vague about it, though.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. We are working on making the experience better when this happens, and we will take care of the error message issue you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eitan and I have worked this out.

It turns out this is due to the subscription being suspended (as artrejo-msft suggested).